# Xcode how to remove default SDK, Don't use SDK,use own header

Tags: linux, xcode, macos, build, sdk

I'm writing code for raspberry pi with Xcode6.2.  I tried to put a raspberry SDK (includes linux headers, etc) package into Xcode directory `.platform->Developer->SDKs`, then restart Xcode, new project, choose new SDK (will show in build setting if SDK format is correct), and Xcode crashes.

I can correctly read some of the header files that are not included in the MacOS, but most common functions do not work. The same file name will be overwritten by MacOS SDK.  Whether the required header files is included or not, Xcode will automatically locate function from SDK.

Any idea how to remove default SDK? Make Xcode not look for functions in MacOS SDK, my Xcode only allows to switch SDK between macos10.10 and 10.9

I need to look at the structure of the function all the time, Xcode search speed is the best compare with other editor.

Answer (score 0):

set Enable Modules (C and Objective-C) of Target solved this problem